# How to clear a PBS job dependency using qalter?

Tags: hpc, pbs

Say I sent a job with a dependency using `qsub -W depend=afterok:JOBID` to the cluster, how to I clear it with qalter command (using PBSpro scheduler)? I found Some info in the `qalter` [man page](http://qcd.phys.cmu.edu/QCDcluster/pbs/PBS_qalter.html), but couldn't find how to clear it, just how to create a new dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help from some friends I got an answer, apparently I had to submit a `qalter` command to alter the dependency, but instead of specifying a new `JOBID`, just omitting the `:JOBID`.

### Example:

Submit a job that depends on successful completion of a previous job (say `1234`)

```
qsub -q my_queue -l ... -W depend=afterok:1234 file.pbs
```

The newly submitted job will stay on-hold until job `1234` finishes with `ExitStatus:0`. We can check the JobId and status of the newly submitted job using the `qstat` command (its status should be H for Hold and say its Id is `1235`).
Then if we decide that we don't need to wait for the first command to finish, we 
can clear the dependency:

```
qalter -W depend=afterok 1235
```

Note that I ommited the colon and the dependency Id after `afterok` and that `qalter` requires the JobId it's altering as its last argument.

Comment: PBSPro 19.0.0 responds to `qalter -W depend=afterok 5728152` with `qalter: illegal -W value`.

Comment: @jacob, you should have a `:` between and not space before the jobid.
Try using `qalter -W depend=afterok:5728152`.
Cheers, Ido

Comment: In your answer you state that erasing a dependency is done by removing the ":dependencyId" part. This is what I did. The number 5728152 is the job to alter.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry.
I'm not sure why it's not working, are you sure that your job (5728152) is still in the queue?